# Pivoting a large data file

Tags: java, unix, pivot, transpose

I have some large tab delimited data files.These files will have a few orders of magnitude more rows than columns. The problem is that I'd like to pivot these files, but in this case "large" is being defined as being too big to do this in memory.

I was hoping to find some suggestions on the fastest way of doing this. I'm primarily working in Java on UNIX, although if a faster language specific solution were to arise (or something using awk, etc) I'd be open to that as well.

Currently we're doing this in memory but as things evolve over time the files are exceeding our memory capacities. Obviously "buy a larger machine" is a solution, but not in the cards at the moment.

Comment: I assume you want the result files to be the same names?

Comment: No, actually the opposite is the ideal case although it doesn't matter that much as we could make a copy of the file beforehand.

Comment: What do you mean by pivoting?

Comment: Can you see if the example I linked to works for you? It basically does what my answer says it does... I have tested it with inputs which  certainly are not as large as yours (only 2MB large files) but it Works For Me(tm).

Comment: Nayuki: If you view the data as a matrix, transposing the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below may work for you. This code first opens the source file as a `BufferedReader`, then reads the first line and splits it against `\t`.

The resulting array's length is the number of lines of the destination file. A new array of `FileHolder` objects is created, where a `FileHolder` basically holds a file descriptor and a `ByteBuffer` to use as a cache (so as not to write each and every word). When all holders are created, the first line is written.

Then the source file is read again, split again, line by line, until empty, and all file holders appended to.

When done, the destination file is created (at last) and all FileHolder instances are written to it in the array order, therefore in line order.

Here is a sample code (LONG, also available [here](https://gist.github.com/1487203)). It can certainly be improved (resources are not really closed at the correct place etc) but it works. It transposes a 275 MB file here in around 25 seconds (quad core Q6600, 4 GB RAM, x86_64 Linux 3.1.2-rc5), and runs with the "flimsy" default value of 64 MB of Sun's (64bit) JDK:

```
package net.sf.jpam;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class Test
{
    private static final Pattern TAB = Pattern.compile("\t");

    private static class FileHolder
    {
        private static final byte TABCHAR[] = "\t".getBytes();
        // Size of the buffer size
        private static final int BUFSZ = 32768;

        // Format string for a file
        private static final String FORMAT = "/home/fge/t2.txt.%d";

        // The ByteBuffer
        private final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFSZ);

        // The File object
        private final File fd;

        // RandomAccessFile
        private final RandomAccessFile file;

        FileHolder(final int index)
            throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            final String name = String.format(FORMAT, index);
            fd = new File(name);
            file = new RandomAccessFile(fd, "rw");
        }

        public void write(final String s)
            throws IOException
        {
            final byte[] b = s.getBytes();
            if (buf.remaining() < b.length + TABCHAR.length)
                flush();
            buf.put(b).put(TABCHAR);
        }

        private void flush()
            throws IOException
        {
            file.write(buf.array(), 0, buf.position());
            buf.position(0);
        }

        public void copyTo(final RandomAccessFile dst)
            throws IOException
        {
            flush();
            final FileChannel source = file.getChannel();
            final FileChannel destination = dst.getChannel();
            source.force(false);
            final long len = source.size() - TABCHAR.length;

            source.transferTo(0, len, destination);
            dst.writeBytes("\n");

        }

        public void tearDown()
            throws IOException
        {
            file.close();
            if (!fd.delete())
                System.err.println("Failed to remove file " + fd);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return fd.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        long before, after;

        before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final Reader r = new FileReader("/home/fge/t.txt");
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);

        /*
         * Read first line, count the number of elements. All elements are
         * separated by a single tab.
         */
        String line = reader.readLine();
        String[] elements = TAB.split(line);

        final int nrLines = elements.length;
        final FileHolder[] files = new FileHolder[nrLines];

        /*
         * Initialize file descriptors
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < nrLines; i++)
            files[i] = new FileHolder(i);


        /*
         * Write first lines, then all others
         */
        writeOneLine(elements, files);

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            elements = TAB.split(line);
            writeOneLine(elements, files);
        }

        reader.close();
        r.close();
        after = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Read time: " + (after - before));

        before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final RandomAccessFile out = new RandomAccessFile("/home/fge/t2.txt",
            "rw");

        for (final FileHolder file: files) {
            file.copyTo(out);
            file.tearDown();
        }

        out.getChannel().force(false);
        out.close();

        after = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Write time: " + (after - before));
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static void writeOneLine(final String[] elements,
        final FileHolder[] fdArray)
        throws IOException
    {  
        final int len = elements.length;
        String element;
        FileHolder file;

        for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
            element = elements[index];
            file = fdArray[index];
            file.write(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but it doesn't seem to solve the memory footprint issue. For instance, on a 4.5GB file I wasn't able to run this with -Xmx4000. The files we have are often larger than the available RAM so a solution that uses less RAM than the file size is needed.

Comment: By curiosity, can you run this command on one such 4.5 GB file: `head -1 thefile|wc -c`?

Comment: 16968 ... Could the problem be due to exceeding the buffer size? (I'm not in a position to tweak that at the moment)

Comment: It's not that much... The problem is therefore that too much RAM is mapped. Three questions: 1. are all lines the same length or of different length? 2. do you mind if data is (temporarily) duplicated? 3. how many file descriptors can you open at a maximum?

Comment: 1) In terms of columns, all lines are the same. Can't guarantee the same # of bytes. 2) If it works, so be it 3) ~3.1M

Comment: Ack sorry, that was for the system (file-max). ulimit -n shows 131K

Comment: OK, I'll assume that 131k is enough, after all one line is not even 17k long ;)

Comment: OK, can you go to the same link? The code has completely changed. TO my surprise, it is not that much longer. But it eats a LOT less memory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5930/discussion-between-fge-and-geoffjentry)

Comment: Have you had a chance to try yet?

Answer (score 0):

@fge:
1) It is better to use CharBuffer instead of instantiating lot of Strings.

2) It is better to use Pattern Matching like this:

```
initially..

private Matcher matcher;
Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile( pattern );
matcher = regexPattern.matcher("");

and then for matching pattern.. you do this..

matcher.reset(charBuffer).find()
```

because, when you look inside

```
Pattern.matcher(CharSequence input) {
 Matcher m = new Matcher(this, input);
}
```

Always refrain from writing code that causes a lot of instantiation or String usage. This causes a lot of memory usage which causes a performance drain.

Comment: That will not work for data as large as what is involved here -- and anyway my code has flaws which I am currently fixing: I can now write 256MB files with a 64MB heap size. What's more, it doesn't need the regex to remove the final tab